# Delete an instantiation of a class inside of the class itself once a condition is met

Tags: c++, class, oop, arduino-c++

I am making an infinite runner game on a 16x2 LCD display in Arduino.

The enemies crawl to the left across the screen and when they reach the end I want the instance of the enemy class to be deleted but I don't know how. I want it to delete itself inside of the update function once the x position gets to zero.

Anyway heres my code:

The class:

```
class Enemy {
private:
  int xPos, yPos;
public:
  Enemy::Enemy(int xPos, int yPos) {
    this->xPos = xPos;
    this->yPos = yPos;
  }

  draw() {
    lcd.setCursor(xPos, yPos);
    lcd.print("E");
  }

  move() {
    //erase enemy at last position
    lcd.setCursor(xPos, yPos);
    lcd.print(" ");
    //move enemy
    xPos--;
    if(xPos == 0){
      delete(this);
    }
  }
};
```

and here's the rest:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
// with the arduino pin number it is connected to
const int rs = 7, en = 8, d4 = 9, d5 = 10, d6 = 11, d7 = 12, buttonPin = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd = LiquidCrystal(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
unsigned int playerYPos = 1, buttonPrevious;
const long playerUpdateInterval = 32, enemyMoveInterval = 500;
unsigned long lastUpdatedPlayerMillis = 0, lastMovedEnemiesMillis;



class Enemy {
private:
  int xPos, yPos;
public:
  Enemy::Enemy(int xPos, int yPos) {
    this->xPos = xPos;
    this->yPos = yPos;
  }

  draw() {
    lcd.setCursor(xPos, yPos);
    lcd.print("E");
  }

  move() {
    //erase enemy at last position
    lcd.setCursor(xPos, yPos);
    lcd.print(" ");
    //move enemy
    xPos--;
    if(xPos == 0){
      delete(this);
    }
  }
};

Enemy e(15, 1);

void drawPlayer() {
  lcd.setCursor(1, playerYPos);
  lcd.print("P");
}



void updatePlayer() {
  uint8_t button = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  //check if button is pressed
  if (button == LOW && buttonPrevious == HIGH) {
    //erase player at last position
    lcd.setCursor(1, playerYPos);
    lcd.print(" ");
    //move player
    playerYPos = 1 - playerYPos;
  }
  buttonPrevious = digitalRead(buttonPin);
}

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  //initialize the pushbutton pin
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  buttonPrevious = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  //update player 30 times a second
  if (currentMillis - lastUpdatedPlayerMillis >= playerUpdateInterval) {
    //reset counter since last updated
    lastUpdatedPlayerMillis = currentMillis;
    updatePlayer();
  };
  //move enemies ??? times a second
  if(currentMillis - lastMovedEnemiesMillis >= enemyMoveInterval) {
    lastMovedEnemiesMillis = currentMillis;
    e.move();
  }
  drawPlayer();
  e.draw();
}
```

I've tried using the `delete()` function and looking up things along the lines of "how to delete an instance of a class or object inside itself" on google.

Currently, it acts just fine until its `x` position hits `zero` and then it declines to delete itself and, despite the `xPos` values being negative, the enemy kinda glitches out on screen and walks left but re-spawns semi-randomly in the middle of the display.

Comment: Ok ill ask there too thanks for your help.

Comment: why not recycle the object for the next?

Comment: Your member functions `draw()` and `move()` need to have a return type declared.  Once you do that, you have a way to indicate removal of the `Enemy` object to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the destructor of a class from one of its methods is not a good idea. `delete()` will invoke class deallocator, and [is meant to destroy a class instance that was created using the `new` expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete). You don't know, in general, how this class instance was created; it could have been allocated on the stack, in which case the result is unpredictable.

In your case, a global instance of your class is instantiated, which must not be deallocated using `delete` at all.

A few suggestions for your code:

- keep a global pointer to your class instance(s). Have your `setup()` to spawn your class instance(s) and keep track of it using your pointer(s), and `loop()` to delete instances when needed (and potentially respawn new instances).
- Inside your `Enemy` class, maintain a status that can be consumed from `loop()` via a method, so you can identify when the class instance is ready be deleted.
- When implementing your pointers, check if the Arduino SDK supports [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). This should alleviate the need for raw `new`/`delete` instructions.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks! this points me in the right direction. Ill post an update when I get it all fixed up.